# Using has_one and belongs_to in the same class for ruby association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create statuses that will have a user that creates the status and a user that the status is about.

Very similar to "tagging" someone in a facebook post.  I need the user who creates the post to be the owner, but i also need to figure out some way to associate the user that the status is about with the actual status.

The end goal is to display all the status about a certain user.

I have a status class.

```
class Status < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, presence: true,
                      length: { minimum: 2}

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

I also have a user class

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :first_name, presence: true

  validates :last_name, presence: true

  validates :profile_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true,
                          format: {
                            with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\z/,
                            message: 'Must be formatted correctly'
                          }

  has_many :statuses
end
```

I originally thought to add

```
has_one :user
```

to my status class but I am now realizing that this can't be the best implementation.

Can anyone help me with this association?

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense that a user should be able to create more than one status and tag more than one user in a single status. Therefore, you should use `has_many`, rather than `has_one`.

As for creating multiple associations with the same class:

```
class Status < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :referred_users, through: :mentions, source: :user
end

class Mention < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :status
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :statuses, foreign_key: 'creator_id'
  has_many :referring_statuses, through: :mentions, source: :status
end
```

Comment: was just about to post an answer saying a through table is needed, but as your edit has fixed the problem with the previous answer. I will just upvote and move along ;)

Comment: @JohnHayes-Reed, yea, I said he needs many to many and for some reason I didn't do it. It's 4:30 AM here :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in this case you can have a straight user to status model, since user can have many status, and status can have many users (user who created it, and user tagged in the status if I'm understanding it correctly).

I suggest that you create a model between status and user, call it Status_Info, and create a info attribute which denotes whether the record was made for the creator or the tagged person.

And to find all status about a user, you just have to look for that user_id in the Status_Info model. i.e. Status_Info.where(user_id: wanted_user_id)